# Set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults with Python/SUDS

Tags: python, exception, suds

How can I set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` with Python/SUDS? For one of my requests, I am getting this error message:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 702, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.'
```

There is no obvious error in the request, so I would like to obtain additional information, but can't find a way using SUDS API. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it now, the answer is no. The `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` setting seems to be only accessible on the server, there doesn't seem to be a way to change it from the client side.